# How to test whether a given vector has three elements of one type and two of another

Tags: r, vector

Say I have the vector of size 5:

```
 b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
 a = sample(b, 5, replace = FALSE)
```

How would I test whether such a vector does or does not have three same elements of one number AND two elements of another same number when there are 13 different numbers to make the vector out of. The thirteen different numbers are in this case the digits 1-13. I know several functions of r such as duplicated() or rle(), but I can't seem to think of how test this situation without using an extremely complicated if() statement.

So far, what I've done is converted the vector to a logical (0 and 1) vector for each digit, and tried summing the logical vector, but with thirteen initial possibilities, that will take too long.

Comment: Please use valid R syntax to show your vector. It seems like you want `table(a)` and check that there is a 3 and a 2 and the rest are 0's.

Comment: Also please clarify if order matters for you vector, whether "type 1" refers to whatever the first element of the vector is or if it is a specific digit, and what needs to be generalizable about your test. 3-5 examples of input and desired output would help a lot in understanding what you need.

Comment: @Gregor: So from this vector: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13) I am using sample() with replacement to obtain some vector: (a vector with 5 elements). I need to check whether the vector produced contains 3 of the same number, and two same numbers of another number, order not mattering

Comment: Please edit that into your question using valid R syntax.

Comment: @Gregor see above

Comment: also you can get numbers 1 to 13 with 1:13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the table function to get unique counts and unname to get the values from the table. Then test for the counts you're interested in.

```
 a = c(3,3,3,4,4,13)
 counts = unname(table(a))
 3 %in% counts & 2 %in% counts
```